# react-three-fiber attachArray broken

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

For some reason I can't seem to add multiple textures to my mesh with attachArray. Attaching a single texture works but if I change attach="material" to attachArray="material", my mesh vanishes. I'm on Three version 0.126.1.

```
return (
        <mesh
            geometry={nodes.tshirt.geometry}
        >
            <a.meshStandardMaterial
                attachArray="material"
                color={props.color}
            />
            <meshStandardMaterial
                attachArray="material"
                map={logo}
                transparent={true}
            />
        </mesh>
    );
```

Comment: See https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/2224 for a workaround